# NHibernate 3CR1: Fetching strategy problems

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

[Continuation to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274678/nhibernate-3cr1-conversion-to-sql-generates-sql-syntax-problem-of-unnecessary-b), I tried to avoid the problem another way:

Just for the reminder:

> My database schema is described below:
>
> Form <-> Log
>
> <--->>Seller1
>
> <--->>Seller2
>
> <--->>Seller3
>
> I have a major entity (Form), one to
>   one relationship to another object
>   (Log) And one to many relationship to
>   the childs (Sellers).
>
> I want to pull out all the Forms that
>   one of their Sellers meets certain
>   conditions.

I tried like this now:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_Get_Forms_Where_CorporationNumber_Is_510778087_Metohd1()
    {
        var CorporationNumber = "513514950";

        var list1 = sellerRepository
                    .Where(x => x.CorporationNumber == CorporationNumber)
                    .Select(x => x.Form)
                    .Fetch(x => x.Log)
                    .Take(10).ToList();

        CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty(list1);
    }
```

But unfortunately I get NullReferenceException:

> TestUsingDevelopmentDataBase.Moch.BillOfSale.Data.FormRepositoryTests.Can_Get_Forms_Where_CorporationNumber_Is_510778087_Metohd1:
>   System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

**EDIT:** stacktrace:

> at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ProcessFetch.Process(FetchRequestBase
>   resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor
>   queryModelVisitor, IntermediateHqlTree
>   tree) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\ResultOperatorProcessors\ProcessFetch.cs:line
>   11 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ProcessFetchOne.Process(FetchOneRequest
>   resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor
>   queryModelVisitor, IntermediateHqlTree
>   tree) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\ResultOperatorProcessors\ProcessFetchOne.cs:line
>   9 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ResultOperatorProcessor`1.Process(ResultOperatorBase
>   resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor
>   queryModel, IntermediateHqlTree tree)
>   in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\ResultOperatorProcessors\ResultOperatorProcessor.cs:line
>   17 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ResultOperatorMap.Process(ResultOperatorBase
>   resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor
>   queryModel, IntermediateHqlTree tree)
>   in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\ResultOperatorProcessors\ResultOperatorMap.cs:line
>   24 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitResultOperator(ResultOperatorBase
>   resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel,
>   Int32 index) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\QueryModelVisitor.cs:line
>   125 at
>   Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperatorBase.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor
>   visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32
>   index) at
>   Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitResultOperators(ObservableCollection`1
>   resultOperators, QueryModel
>   queryModel) at
>   Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
>   in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\QueryModelVisitor.cs:line
>   96 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel
>   queryModel, VisitorParameters
>   parameters, Boolean root) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\Visitors\QueryModelVisitor.cs:line
>   49 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor
>   sessionFactory) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhLinqExpression.cs:line
>   67 at
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String
>   queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 filters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs:line
>   27 at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String
>   expressionStr, IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLExpressionQueryPlan.cs:line
>   34 at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String
>   expressionStr, IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLExpressionQueryPlan.cs:line
>   23 at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String
>   expressionStr, IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLExpressionQueryPlan.cs:line
>   17 at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\QueryPlanCache.cs:line
>   88 at
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:line
>   302 at
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:line
>   258 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression
>   expression, IQuery& query,
>   NhLinqExpression& nhQuery) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs:line
>   42 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs:line
>   25 at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs:line
>   102 at
>   Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   TestUsingDevelopmentDataBase.Moch.BillOfSale.Data.FormRepositoryTests.Can_Get_Forms_Where_CorporationNumber_Is_510778087_Metohd1()
>   in
>   D:\Dev\NCommon\Moch.BillOfSale\Moch.BillOfSale.NHibenate.Tests\FormRepositoryTests.cs:line
>   207

The problem could be circumvented in a less well, as follows:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_Get_Forms_Where_CorporationNumber_Is_510778087_Metohd2()
    {
        var CorporationNumber = "513514950";

        var list2 = sellerRepository
                                .Where(x => x.CorporationNumber == CorporationNumber)
                                .Fetch(x => x.Form).ThenFetch(x => x.Log)
                                .Take(10).ToList().Select(x => x.Form);

        CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty(list2);
    }
```

But of course we all prefer the elegant way and want to understand what lies behind the problem

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: If anything, NH should throw a more specific exception than NRE. Can you create and submit a test case to the NH Jira?

Comment: issue is here http://216.121.112.228/browse/NHLQ-82

Comment: @ari: try and create a *stand-alone* test case that reproduces the issue, otherwise devs probably won't look at it.

Comment: Does this behavior still occur when using the latest general release of NHibernate? (RC versions often have internal implementation bugs; release (GA) versions are often more stable.)

Answer (score 0):

I think Nhibernate doesn't like you fetching after a select. I ran into a null reference exception just like you did.

See my question here about it.

[In Linq-to-Nhibernate, is it possible to use .Fetch() after a .Select()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497073/in-linq-to-nhibernate-is-it-possible-to-use-fetch-after-a-select)

You might be able to .Select(x => x.Form) after your fetching in your second example before you .ToList() it, too.

I'm using Nhibernate 3.2 and this is still an issue. There should be a proper 'you can't fetch after a select' exception or something to spare us some pain.